# calling URLconnection on another method

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, urlconnection

I have a problem when I want to use a variable of type `URLConnection`.

Here is my `connectToServer()` method:

```
    private int connectToServer(){
        try {
            URL u = new URL("http://192.168.1.121:5000/");
            URLConnection con = u.openConnection();
            con.setDoOutput(true);
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 1;
    }
```

I want to use variable `con` in `sendToServer()` method, here is the code:

```
    public String sendToServer(String data){
        try {
            OutputStreamWriter streamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
            streamWriter.write(data);
            waktu_kirim = GetUTCdatetimeAsString();
            streamWriter.flush();


            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            reader.close();
            Log.d("RESPONSE", sb.toString());
            return sb.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
    }
```

but I got error result telling that `con` variable is null. How can I use the variable `con` that maintain connection with server?

Comment: Hello, this is not Javascript code, it looks more like Java. You should remove (if possible) the javascript tag from your post and add the java one ;)

Comment: oh yeah, i mean its java, hahah
can you help me out sir?

Answer (score 0):

`con` is a local variable in method `connectToServer()`. If you want to use the variable's value (after initializing it in `connectToServer()`) in `sendToServer()`, you have to pass it while calling the latter from the former. So, you HAVE to call `sendToServer()` from `connectToServer()`.

```
private int connectToServer(){
    /* initialize con */
    URL u = new URL("http://192.168.1.121:5000/");
    URLConnection con = u.openConnection();
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    ...
    sendToServer(some_string, con);
    return 1;
}

...

public String sendToServer(String s, URLConnection con){
    //here, con is same as the con in connectToServer()
}
```

That's how you normally use a variable from one method in another. However, if you CANNOT call `sendToServer()` from `connectToServer()` for some reasons, you could use a global instance variable in the class, first initialize it in `connectToServer()` and then use it in `sendToServer()`.

```
import java.net.*;
class Myclass{
    public URLConnection con;

    private int connectToServer(){ //this should be called before 
                                  //sendToServer()
        /* initialize con here */
        URL u = new URL("http://192.168.1.121:5000/");
        con = u.openConnection();
        con.setDoOutput(true);
    }

    public String sendToServer(String s){
        //now use con here
    }
}
```

Comment: actually, i want to connect to server immediately after apps opened, and when i press a button, it will send data to server, so i need to call variable con to use it in sendToServer, from the answer you provide, what i got is i need to call sendToServer every time i press a button that means app need to make a connection every time it's sending a data?

Comment: How do you call the `sendToServer()` method??

Comment: @M.AgusTriMulyono Actually `HttpURLConnection.connect()` doesn't create a TCP connection. See the Javadoc. You're misusing this object, and you have a trival variable-scoping problem as well.

Comment: I'm sure the `connectToServer()` method is called before the `sendToServer()` method is. It has to be. I don't understand why using a global instance variable can't solve your problem. No matter how you call `sendToServer()`, the `con` object will always be in its scope.

Comment: Don' you get an error saying `can't find variable con` in method `sendToServer()`???

Comment: @progy_rock Evidently he has a second `con` as an instance or static variable of the class.

Comment: @EJP That can be presumed though. But the way he has titled the question, it seems that he wants to use the local variable in another method.

Comment: @M.AgusTriMulyono Can you show us your entire code?

Comment: @progy_rock Of course, and all he has to do is to accomplish that is to remove the local declaration inside the method. However he will then run up against the problem that `HttpURLConnection` objects (1) aren't actually connected by `connect()` and (2) can't be re-used. What he really needs is a local variable created on demand, not an instance variable at all. There's no point whatsoever in saving `HttpURLConnections` as instance variables.

Comment: @progy_rock I have already provided an answer of my own. I don't see any point in discussing your code or my views on it under a different answer.

Comment: i just wondering is there any way to maintain connection between client and server, so if i want to send data, my app doesnt bother to make connection again?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a problem when I want to use a variable of type `URLConnection`.

Your problem is that you have *two* such variables.

```
            URLConnection con = u.openConnection();
```

Here is one of them. It is a method-local variable, and you aren't returning it, so it disappears as soon as it goes out of scope.

```
        return 1;
```

And here is where it goes out of scope. The point of returning a constant `1` escapes me. Change the method and its signature to return `con`.

> I want to use variable `con` in `sendToServer()` method

But you aren't. You're declaring and using another one.

```
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
```

And here, whatever `con` might be, it isn't the `con` that was declared and initialized in the previous method.

> but I got error result telling that `con` variable is null.

I agree. It's null. You never changed it from null.

> How can I use the variable `con` that maintain connection with server?

Use the one that was created in the first method. But as a matter of fact you should *delete* the first method, and create a new `HttpURLConnection` via similar means every time you need one. Your apparent objective of connecting to the server once and re-using this connection for multiple requests is not attainable; nor is it even necessary given that `HttpURLConnection` does connection-pooling behind the scenes.

Comment: is it possible to maintain connection with server when my app starts til it closed, so when i send data, my app doesn't bother to make connection again?
because from what i found on internet, i need to make connection every time i send data

Comment: @M.AgusTriMulyono Please read my answer. I've covered exactly that in the last paragraph.